# Flip column values in NumPy matrix while preserving NaN values and respecting duplicate values

Tags: python, numpy

I want to flip the values in each column of a NumPy matrix. The function should leave NaN values as they are in the output matrix and duplicate values should be replaced by their flipped counterpart. Here's an example of an input and output matrix:

```py
A = np.array([
    [1.0,2.0,3.0],
    [np.nan,2.0,np.nan],
    [2.0,1.0,np.nan],
    [3.0,np.nan,1.0]
    ])

A_flipped = np.array([
    [3.0,1.0,1.0],
    [np.nan,1.0,np.nan],
    [2.0,2.0,np.nan],
    [1.0,np.nan,3.0]
    ])
```

Comment: Is it only for 4x3 array, could it be 6x5 ?

Comment: Should work for any shape

Comment: you've accepted an answer but it does not produce the result you expected. Any "partial" answer is ok?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work! Unmarked the answer.

Comment: Also, regarding duplicates, consider that you have the following 5x4 array https://justpaste.it/2xmvx with multiple pairs of duplicates per axis, how should they be replaced in such case?

Comment: The logic shouldn't change. So in your provided example, the last column 2,2,3,3,1 should be flipped to 2,2,1,1,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def flip_column_values(A):
    
    A_copy = np.copy(A)
    
    for col in A_copy.T:
        values = col[~np.isnan(col)] # get all non-missing values in column
        values_sorted = np.sort(values) # sort them ascending
  
        # create new array with flipped values
        values_new = np.empty_like(values) # get
        for i in range(len(values_sorted)):
            flipped = values_sorted[len(values_sorted)-i-1]
            values_new[values==values_sorted[i]] = flipped
        
        col[~np.isnan(col)] = values_new
        
    return A_copy

# test if function delivers right output
output = flip_column_values(A)
np.testing.assert_equal(output,A_flipped)
```

Comment: Does not seem to work, maybe test using `output = flip_values(A)`and then 
`assert np.array_equal(A_flipped,output)`?

Comment: @JohannesWiesner Just changed to use flipud, not fliplr. sorry about that. Also you can try `np.array_equal(np.array([np.nan]),np.array([np.nan]))` and it will show `False`. np.nan does not equal anything, including np.nan. Also on closer inspection, the A_flipped that you describe is inconsistent. The mid column that goes from  2,2,1,nan to 1,1,2,nan ?

Comment: It also doesn't work with `np.flipud`. I checked the middle column, looks fine. The original array contains 1s, 2s, and NaNs. Since 2 is the maximum and 1 is the minimum these values get flipped and the NaN value stays untouched. Therefore 2,2,1,nan becomes 1,1,2,nan. If a column holds an uneven number of unique values (let's say 1,2,nan,3), the median value should stay as it is and all other values should get flipped (3,2,nan,1)

Comment: @JohannesWiesner Added the code to replace numbers based on sorting order. It isn't clear from the question, and I assumed flip mean simply flipping the array

Comment: Looks better now. Could you write one function that takes in `A` and outputs `A_flipped`? That would make it easier to read your code :)

Comment: Functions in Python must not start with a number. Could you write one function that works for a 2D-matrix? Besides, it looks good to me. You're right, the testing only works with `np.testing.assert_equal(A_flipped,your_function(A))`

Comment: nice, I didn't know about np.testing. Also changed the names. Personally I think the single function version looks a bit complex.

Answer (score 0):

I the meantime I also came up with my own two-function solution that uses dictionary mapping with `np.vectorize`. It also uses `np.apply_along_axis` instead of a for-loop. Both `np.vectorize` and `np.apply_along_axis` might be faster for large arrays. Also note, that with dictionary mapping there's no need to impute `np.nan` values, so we also save some lines of code:

```py
def _reverse_array_values(a):
    unique_vals = np.unique(a[~np.isnan(a)])  # Get unique non-nan values
    flip_dict = dict(zip(unique_vals,np.flip(unique_vals)))  # Create flip dictionary
    return np.vectorize(flip_dict.get)(a)  # map old values onto new values

def flip_column_values(A):
    A_ = np.apply_along_axis(_reverse_array_values,0,A)
    return A_

output = flip_column_values(A)
np.testing.assert_equal(output,A_flipped)
```